# git branch commit ahead of/behind master infinite loop

Tags: git, github

im new to git

i create a branch on my local called `orm` and pushed it to the github
when i check the branch on github i see

[image]

which says `this branch is 1 commit ahead of master` which makes sense but when i create a pull request and confirm the pull merging it with master branch the status changes to

[image]

now it says  `this branch is 1 commit behind master`

if i click on it asks me to create a pull request to merge master into orm branch

[image]

and if i do that it goes back to `this branch is 1 commit ahead of master`

it never seems to end ....so my question , is that even something that i should be concerned about ?! i mean obviously i should created a pull request for `1 commit ahead if master` when i push my code to github ... but should i ignore `this branch is 1 commit behind master` which shows after pull request confirmation ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but should i ignore "this branch is 1 commit behind master" which shows after pull request confirmation

**tl;dr:** Probably, yes, you can ignore it if you don't wish to tweak your workflow.

**Details:**

To be sure if you can ignore it, you need to understand *why* this is happening. When completing a Pull Request, there are different options. The default option is to create a merge commit. In your case that creates 1 new commit on `master` that isn't on `orm` and this is why after the PR is completed `orm` is instantly 1 commit behind. When this happens, you can safely ignore it. The next time you complete a PR from `orm` into `master`, you'll be 2 commits behind, the next time 3 commits behind, etc. As long as the diff between `orm` and `master` has no changes, you can safely ignore this.

At some point, if a different branch gets merged into `master`, then `orm` will be even more commits behind, and the diffs will no longer match, and that is when you should consider merging `master` back into `orm` again.

**Additional Notes:**

1. There are other merge options when [completing PRs on GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/configuring-pull-request-merges/about-merge-methods-on-github) called "Squash Commits" and "Rebase and merge". In your case you don't want these either because in both of those GitHub rewrites the commits (even for rebase when a rebase isn't needed). With those options your `orm` branch will end up being 1 commit ahead and 1 commit behind. GitHub doesn't currently have an option of fast-forward merge, which is what you would need to have the branches be identical after the PR is completed. Consider one of the following options to solve your issue, or just ignore it.
2. Do you really need a long-lived `orm` branch? Depending on your team's branching strategy, you could consider using feature branches instead of `orm` and every time you start working on something you can simply branch off of the latest `master`, and then that branch will already have all those merge commits and will be fully up to date.
3. After completing the PR of `orm` into `master`, locally, you could consider merging the latest `master` into `orm` to get that merge commit onto `orm` before you start adding more commits to it. Note this is very similar to [crystal's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72658281/184546) of pulling `master` into `orm`. Whether you use the `--rebase` flag is up to you, and would depend on whether you have other people sharing the `orm` branch with you or not. If you always do this immediately after completing the PR of `orm` into `master`, it shouldn't make a difference whether you use rebase or not.

Comment: thanx buddy you explained everything  , i do a pull of master in local branch before committing new changes .... this should do the trick  

if i click on `this branch is 1 commit behind master` and merge master into orm in github ... it'll be a nightmare trying to push new changes from my local branch , i assume it's cuz my local `orm` is different from online `orm`

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider the case that `orm` branch is `1` commit behind `master`.

> **Switch to local `orm` branch**

```
git checkout orm
```

> **This will show the count difference between the branches, here `orm` is
> `1` commit behind `master`**

```
git rev-list --count orm..master
```

> **This will fetch changes and reset local `orm` branch according to
> remote `master` branch**

```
git fetch origin; git reset --hard origin/master
```

> **This will push local `orm` branch changes to remote `orm` branch**

```
git push origin orm
```

Refresh the github repository page and hopefully you will find your problem solved.

`P.S. I personally solved same issue using above steps.`

Answer (score 1):

After you create a pull-request, as long when comparing between base and master is Green then all should be good.

Usually before I start the development, always pull/download the latest code:

```
git pull origin <branchName> --rebase
```

Note: In your case, replace `<branchName>` with master.